# Writing a Factory method for STL random number generators

Tags: c++, design-patterns, random, c++17

I'm trying to provide an interface — through a config file — for my users to choose a distribution for some of the parameters that they are using. I would like to use STL random number generator algorithms for this purpose.

Let's assume that my program reads a JSON from a command line. For the JSON provided below, the program needs to realize that it should generate a random number from the normal distribution with given mean and standard variation. (I'm using the same parameter names as STL library for clearance.)

```
{
    "dist": "normal_distribution",
    "mean": 0.1,
    "stddev": 0.5
}
```

So far, I can parse the JSON easily, and use each distribution's `param_type` to initialize the distribution. I use the name to decide which distribution to decide the `param_type` and the distribution.

What I don't know is how to implement this nicely. I know that I should provide some sort of factory method for this, pass the JSON, and spit out a function or a class. If I want to return an instance of a class, let's say a `unique_ptr` of the generator, I need to define an abstract class, e.g., `RandDist` and write some sort of adaptor to incorporate my input, .... I generally don't need a lot from the class, just a `gen()` method should be enough.

I'm wondering if anyone have thoughts on this. Or, if anyone knows a library that can do this.

P.S. Input doesn't have to be a JSON object, any hash table would work per se.

Comment: Seems to me that you're pretty clear on the diraction you should be taking. As food for thought, an interface with a single virtual function can be seen as a functor, so `std::function`'s type-erasure functionality migh come in handy here.

Comment: @Quentin I think what I don't like much about my approach is the amount of adaptors that I need to write for all algorithm. I somehow hope there is a nicer way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to keep the boilerplate to a bare minimum. Assumptions:

- You know the type of your generator in advance (that's easily switchable if you need your generators to be dynamic as well)
- All of the distributions generate `double`s (that's pretty much baked in since the API has to return *something* concrete to be decently usable)
- All of the distributions are constructible from `double` parameters (that's tweakable as well with a proxy object, but depending on your actual JSON library the work may already be done there)
- I've used a GCC preprocessor extension to handle the zero-parameter case, but the macro can certainly be rewritten to not need it.

```
using Generator = std::mt19937;
using Distribution = std::function<double(Generator &)>;
using Json = std::map<std::string, std::string>;

template <class DistributionType, class... Parameters>
Distribution make_distribution_impl(Json const &json, Parameters... parameters) {
    return DistributionType{std::stod(json.at(parameters))...};
}

Distribution make_distribution(Json const &json) {
    auto const &distributionName = json.at("dist");

    #define generate_distribution_factory(name_, ...) \
        if(distributionName == #name_) \
            return make_distribution_impl<std::name_<double>>(json, ## __VA_ARGS__)

    generate_distribution_factory(uniform_real_distribution, "a", "b");
    generate_distribution_factory(normal_distribution, "mean", "stddev");
    // ...

    #undef generate_distribution_factory

    throw std::runtime_error{"Unknown distribution " + distributionName};
}
```

[See it live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OQXo3qvRPvAbh4Xg)

Comment: This looks amazing! I think this is what I was looking for but I have to admit I have issue understanding it. I think for the most part, I get the logic behind it but I have a question. Some distributions, e.g., `std::piecewise_linear_distribution` are using container as they parameters, I wonder how you handle those in your approach. I use nlohmann-json to handle those nicely. My idea was to write a parser to each distribution's param_type, and read the parameters, then pass them around. But I don't understand how to do it here. Thanks :-)

Comment: I think removing `std::stod` will do, since nlohmann's json library uses the same syntax, and does the conversion to stl types, ... but I'm asking since I don't fully understand the code for `generate_dis....` part.

Comment: @Amir ... dammit! You using nlohmann-json is great news, since it does have the auto-converting plumbing all set up -- you can simply remove `std::stod()` from `make_distribution_impl` and the magic conversions will kick in for the simple cases. `std::piecewise_linear_distribution` is kind of a chore though, since it takes iterators... The simplest solution is just to not declare it through the macro, but add a separate branch to handle it inside `make_distribution`.

Comment: I'm following but not fully honestly. I get what the macro does, and understand how to expand it but I don't know what I should to support the `std::piecewise_linear_distribution` outside to it :\

Comment: That should be no more than `if(distributionName == "piecewise_linear_distribution ") { /* read in values, handle errors */ return std::piecewise_linear_distribution<double>{ /* what you just parsed */ }; }`

Comment: I'll try to see if I can make it to work :-) I think I see what I should do. Thanks a lot...

Comment: I think I got it, but I'm not gonna lie, I'm having a headache after reading and understanding your code. It was another level for me :D But I now have a reason to learn these stuff more.

Comment: I managed to get all distributions except the `bernoulli_distribution` and `discrete_distribution`! I changed the macro to this, `#define generate_distribution_factory(name_, type_, ...)\ if(distributionName == #name_) return make_distribution_impl<std::name_<type_>>(j, ## __VA_ARGS__);` so that I can specify the type, and be more flexible. However, this doesn't help with the `bool` for some reason! I wonder if you have any idea about this?

Comment: Ah, `bernoulli_distribution` is the only distributioin that's not a template... What a tour! I've made it work by lifting the `<>` pair into the macro argument as well: `#define generate_distribution_factory(name_, suffix_, ...) if(distributionName == #name_) return make_distribution_impl<std::name_ suffix_>(json, ## __VA_ARGS__)`, called as `generate_distribution_factory(bernoulli_distribution, /* empty */, "p");`; but you could also just special-case it. I'm not sure how you're stuck with `discrete_distribution` nor which `bool` you're talking about, though.

Answer (score 5):

You described a pretty standard way to deal with this situation - to have abstract `RandomGenerator` class with just one virtual method `gen()`.

Then, it will have implementations like `NormalDistributionGenerator`, `UniformDistributionGenerator` etc. with constructors accepting appropriate distribution parameter set and initializing STL stuff as members.
These concrete classes will be used directly only in generator creation routine, and used in other places as abstract `RandomGenerator`.

So creation routine will look something like this

```
std::unique_ptr<RandomGenerator> CreateRandomGenerator(const Info& info) {
    switch (info.type) {
    case Type::Normal:
        return std::make_unique<NormalDistributionGenerator>(info.mean(), info.stddev());
    case Type::Uniform:
        return std::make_unique<UniformDistributionGenerator>(info.a(), info.b());
    // ...
    }
}
```

`Info` - is a class which holds distribution info (some JSON wrapper, of map/hash_table - whatever works best in your case).

So you will definitely need to write *some* boilerplate code to make it work, but it will make a usage of your `RandomGenerator` simple and clear, and adding new types of distributions will be easy enough and require code modification in single place only - factory method.