# Using `std::generate` or `std::fill` to fill an `arma::mat`

Tags: c++, random, c++17, std

I'm trying to write a wrapper around the `gmm_full` and `gmm_diag` to have them as `mvnorm_distribution`. I need this specific setup because I'm dealing with an input file, and would like to have everything working more or less the same as `std::*_distribution`s. I have my wrapper and it works as I would like but I have a hard time filling an `arma::mat` via any of the `std` algorithms. Basically, I have something like this:

```cpp
arma::vec gen() {
    // gmm_full model initilization
    return model.generate();
}

void main() {
    arma::mat m(dim, N);
    std::generate(m.begin_col(0), m.end_col(N-1), gen);
}
```

So far, I realized that either the `std::generate` or `m.being_col()` are not working as I was expecting. I was thinking that I'll get a vector and can fill it, or that's what `std::generate` would do but apparently that's not the case. I see in the example that I have to dereference the column but then I cannot do it on `std::generate`. I've both `std::fill` and `std::transform` but I have no success so far.

One solution would be to write a generator class and pass every value one by one, but then that's not what I want really. I was wondering if anyone can help me with this. I'm also aware of the `model.generate(N)` but I'd like to have the distribution wrapped and use it like other `std::*_distribution`s, so it would not solve my problem, or it does and I don't know how to use it.

P.S. This is technically a follow up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56359951/writing-a-factory-method-for-stl-random-number-generators) that I've asked earlier.

Comment: Why don't you use `arma::mat::imbue` which takes a lambda, or `arma::mat::fill` for constant values?

Comment: `imbue` also traverses the `arma::mat` by it's element, col-by-col, and not by it's column. The key distinction here is the fact that `mvnorm_dist` return a vector and the rest of the algorithm return a double, and most iterators are traversing element by element. `arma::mat::begin_col` gives a pointer to a column but I don't know how to use it in a lamba. I think that's the main issue here for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I managed by using [`arma::mat::each_col`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#each_colrow). This accepts an lambda function and basically iterates over columns. So, it would be something like this:

```cpp
    m.each_col([](vec& a) mutable {a = gen();});
```

Don't forget to pass `a` by reference.

Caveat: This is probably slower than the [`arma::gmm_full::generate(N)`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#gmm_diag) or [`arma::mvnrnd`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#mvnrnd). So, if you just want to generate a lot of samples, go with those first.

P.S. `mutable` is not necessary unless you are passing a distribution to the lambda.